# Swift "Cannot convert value of type 'Bool' to expected argument type 'Binding<Bool>'"

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I am trying to make a list of islands that can be favorited and then sorted by favorites. When I try to check if an island.isFavorite it returns the above error. I tried adding a $ in front of the island.isFavorite but then I have an $island not declared in scope. I know the issue is because the variable is binding, just not sure how to solve it here.

Edit: I changed a few things around and have the filter and star working correctly, I am now just missing the correct implementation of the favorite button to modify the isSet state. It is the same error and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to correct the differing bool requirements.

Content view:

```
    import SwiftUI
    
    //a struct to store exactly one island's data
    struct Island: Identifiable, Hashable {
        var id: UUID = UUID()
        let name: String
        let description: String
        let attractions: String
        let photo: String
        let isFavorite: Bool
    }
    
    //a View that shows the data of one island
    struct IslandRow: View {
        var island: Island
        var body: some View {
            HStack {
                Image(island.photo)
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                if island.isFavorite {
                    Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                        .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    struct FavoriteButton: View {
        @Binding var isSet: Bool
    
    
        var body: some View {
            Button {
                isSet.toggle()
            } label: {
                Label("Toggle Favorite", systemImage: isSet ? "star.fill" : "star")
                    .labelStyle(.iconOnly)
                    .foregroundColor(isSet ? .yellow : .gray)
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    struct FavoriteButton_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            FavoriteButton(isSet: .constant(true))
        }
    }
    
    //A view that shows more details about a selected island
    struct IslandDetailsView: View {
        
        var island: Island
        
        var body: some View {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                HStack {
                    IslandRow(island: island)
                        .padding(.trailing, 5)
                    Text(island.name)
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .bold()
                    Spacer()
                    FavoriteButton(isSet: island.isFavorite)
                }
                Text(island.attractions)
                    .padding(.top)
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding()
            .navigationBarTitle(Text(island.name), displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
    
    //create a few islands and then show them in a List
    struct ContentView: View {
        
        @State private var isPresented: Bool = false
        @State private var nameText: String = ""
        @State private var descriptionText: String = ""
        @State private var attractionsText: String = ""
        @State private var editMode = EditMode.inactive
        @State private var showFavoritesOnly = false
        
        
        @State private var islands = [
            Island (name: "Santorini", description: "Aegean sea", attractions: "Best sunset view! Excellent place to get married.", photo: "Santorini", isFavorite: true),
            Island (name: "Mykonos", description: "Aegean sea", attractions: "Cosmopolitan life style. Best night life ever.", photo: "Mykonos", isFavorite: false),
            Island (name: "Skiathos", description: "Aegean sea", attractions: "Amazing local cuisine.", photo: "Skiathos", isFavorite: true),
            Island (name: "Crete", description: "Mediterranean sea.", attractions: "Biggest island. You can find ocean to mountain views.", photo: "Crete", isFavorite: false),
            Island (name: "Corfu", description: "Ionian see", attractions: "Beautifull green landscapes.", photo: "Corfu", isFavorite: false),
            Island (name: "Zakynthos", description: "Aegean sea", attractions: "Many water sports and activities.", photo: "Zakynthos", isFavorite: false),
            Island (name: "Paros", description: "Aegean sea", attractions: "Amazing white rock water front.", photo: "Paros", isFavorite: false)
        ]
        
        var filteredIslands: [Island]{
            islands.filter { island in
                (!showFavoritesOnly || island.isFavorite)
            }
        }
        
        var body: some View {
            
            NavigationView {
                
                ZStack { //used for the overlapping alert box
                    List {
                        Toggle(isOn: $showFavoritesOnly) {
                            Text("Favorites only")
                        }
                        
                        ForEach (filteredIslands, id: \.self) { island in
                            NavigationLink(destination: IslandDetailsView(island: island)) {
                                HStack {
                                    IslandRow(island: island)
                                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                        Text(island.name)
                                            .font(.headline)
                                        Text(island.description)
                                            .foregroundColor( .blue)
                                    }
                                    .padding(7)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        .onDelete(perform: deleteIsland)
                        .onMove(perform: onMove)
                    }
                    .navigationBarTitle("Greek Islands")
                    .navigationBarItems(leading: EditButton(), trailing: addButton)
                    .environment(\.editMode, $editMode)
                    
                    showAlertBox
                }
                
            }
        }
        
        private func deleteIsland(offsets: IndexSet) {
            islands.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
        }
        
        private var addButton: some View {
            switch editMode {
            case .inactive:
                return AnyView(Button(action: {self.isPresented = true})
                    { Image(systemName: "plus")})
            default:
                return AnyView(EmptyView())
            }
        }
        
        //show an alert with textfields to get user input
        private var showAlertBox: some View {
            
            return  AlertTextFieldView(title: "Add New Island", isShown: $isPresented, nameText: $nameText, descriptionText: $descriptionText, attractionsText: $attractionsText, onDone: { _,_,_  in addNewIsland()})
            
        }
        
        private func addNewIsland() {
            
            //a default island photo is added to the list
            let newIsland = Island(name: nameText, description: descriptionText, attractions: attractionsText, photo: "NewIsland", isFavorite: false)
            
            //self.islands.append(newIsland)
            self.islands.insert(newIsland, at: 0)
            
        }
        
        private func onMove(source: IndexSet, destination: Int) {
            islands.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: destination)
        }
        
        struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
            static var previews: some View {
                ContentView()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui) From the `@State` you make a connection all the way through using `@Binding` you are missing that in your in between views. There are also several other issues with your code that can be cleared up by watching "Demystify SwiftUI"

Comment: One thing that is very important, and they will go over it in Demystify SwiftUI, is that you should conform your `Island` struct to `Identifiable`, then in the ForEach, change `ForEach (islands, id: \.self)` to `ForEach (islands)`, otherwise you `.onDelete` may crash things.

Comment: I made some changes from the tutorials mentioned as well as added an edit comment on the post. I am still stuck with the original issue. I'm not sure where in add an @State declaration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all make `isFavorite`a var to make it changeable:

```
struct Island: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id: UUID = UUID() // here better use let
    let name: String
    let description: String
    let attractions: String
    let photo: String
    var isFavorite: Bool // needs to be var to make it changeable
}
```

For passing the island / island.isFavorite in a way that is editable by the subview, there are two ways.

**1. Version 1: pass a Binding down the view hierarchy**
There is a version of `ForEach` that makes this possible, but unfortunately your `filteredIslands` get into the way of it. So you would have to filter directly inline in the ForEach:

```
// ForEach with binding (notice the $ signs), inline filtering
ForEach ($islands.filter { !showFavoritesOnly || $0.wrappedValue.isFavorite}) { $island in
    NavigationLink(destination: IslandDetailsView(island: $island)) { // pass binding here
        HStack {
            IslandRow(island: island)
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(island.name)
                   .font(.headline)
                Text(island.description)
                   .foregroundColor( .blue)
            }
            .padding(7)
        }
    }
}
```

Then in `IslandDetailView` change the passed var to a @Binding too, and pass it with $ to FavoriteButton:

```
struct IslandDetailsView: View {
    
    @Binding var island: Island // change to binding
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            HStack {
                IslandRow(island: island)
                    .padding(.trailing, 5)
                Text(island.name)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .bold()
                Spacer()
                FavoriteButton(isSet: $island.isFavorite) // $ HERE
            }
            Text(island.attractions)
                .padding(.top)
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
        .navigationBarTitle(Text(island.name), displayMode: .inline)
    }
}
```

**2. Version 2: Create a "store" as ObservableObject**
This is a more advanced variant. Define a new class conforming to ObservableObject that holds the list of all islands. The advantage of the ObservableObject is that it can be passed down the view hierarchy using `.environmentObject`.
Then in FavoriteButton you get the store from the environment, search for the relevant index in the list of islands and change it.
Here is the full code:

```
struct Island: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    let name: String
    let description: String
    let attractions: String
    let photo: String
    var isFavorite: Bool // change to var to maek it changeable
}


// define a "store" for the islands as ObservableObject
class IslandsStore: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var islands: [Island] = [
        Island (name: "Santorini", description: "Aegean sea", attractions: "Best sunset view! Excellent place to get married.", photo: "Santorini", isFavorite: true),
        Island (name: "Mykonos", description: "Aegean sea", attractions: "Cosmopolitan life style. Best night life ever.", photo: "Mykonos", isFavorite: false),
        Island (name: "Skiathos", description: "Aegean sea", attractions: "Amazing local cuisine.", photo: "Skiathos", isFavorite: true),
        Island (name: "Crete", description: "Mediterranean sea.", attractions: "Biggest island. You can find ocean to mountain views.", photo: "Crete", isFavorite: false),
        Island (name: "Corfu", description: "Ionian see", attractions: "Beautifull green landscapes.", photo: "Corfu", isFavorite: false),
        Island (name: "Zakynthos", description: "Aegean sea", attractions: "Many water sports and activities.", photo: "Zakynthos", isFavorite: false),
        Island (name: "Paros", description: "Aegean sea", attractions: "Amazing white rock water front.", photo: "Paros", isFavorite: false)
    ]
}


struct IslandRow: View {
    var island: Island
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(island.photo)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
            if island.isFavorite {
                Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                    .foregroundColor(.yellow)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct FavoriteButton: View {
    var island: Island // get full island struct
    
    @EnvironmentObject var store: IslandsStore // get the store from the environment
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            // find passed islandin store and change via index of islands array
            if let index = store.islands.firstIndex(of: island) {
                store.islands[index].isFavorite.toggle()
            }
        } label: {
            Label("Toggle Favorite", systemImage: island.isFavorite ? "star.fill" : "star") // change here
                .labelStyle(.iconOnly)
                .foregroundColor(island.isFavorite ? .yellow : .gray) // change here
        }
    }
}



struct IslandDetailsView: View {
    
    var island: Island
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            HStack {
                IslandRow(island: island)
                    .padding(.trailing, 5)
                Text(island.name)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .bold()
                Spacer()
                FavoriteButton(island: island) // pass island here
            }
            Text(island.attractions)
                .padding(.top)
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
        .navigationBarTitle(Text(island.name), displayMode: .inline)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var isPresented: Bool = false
    @State private var nameText: String = ""
    @State private var descriptionText: String = ""
    @State private var attractionsText: String = ""
    @State private var editMode = EditMode.inactive
    @State private var showFavoritesOnly = false
    
    // create the store
    @StateObject var store = IslandsStore()
    
    var filteredIslands: [Island]{
        store.islands.filter { island in
            (!showFavoritesOnly || island.isFavorite)
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            
            ZStack {
                List {
                    Toggle(isOn: $showFavoritesOnly) {
                        Text("Favorites only")
                    }
                    
                    // ForEach with binding $, inline filtering
                    ForEach (filteredIslands) { island in
                        NavigationLink(destination: IslandDetailsView(island: island)) {
                            HStack {
                                IslandRow(island: island)
                                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                    Text(island.name)
                                        .font(.headline)
                                    Text(island.description)
                                        .foregroundColor( .blue)
                                }
                                .padding(7)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .onDelete(perform: deleteIsland)
                    .onMove(perform: onMove)
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("Greek Islands")
                .navigationBarItems(leading: EditButton(), trailing: addButton)
                .environment(\.editMode, $editMode)
                
//                showAlertBox
            }
        }
        .environmentObject(store) /7 pass the store into the environment
    }
    
    private func deleteIsland(offsets: IndexSet) {
        store.islands.remove(atOffsets: offsets) // refer to store
    }
    
    private var addButton: some View {
        switch editMode {
        case .inactive:
            return AnyView(Button(action: {self.isPresented = true})
                           { Image(systemName: "plus")})
        default:
            return AnyView(EmptyView())
        }
    }
    
    
    private func addNewIsland() {
        
        let newIsland = Island(name: nameText, description: descriptionText, attractions: attractionsText, photo: "NewIsland", isFavorite: false)
        
        store.islands.insert(newIsland, at: 0) // refer to store
        
    }
    
    private func onMove(source: IndexSet, destination: Int) {
        store.islands.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: destination)  // refer to store
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate you taking the time to dumb it down for me.